# How to delete products starting with product ID 2282?

Tags: delete

Magento 2.4.5-p1

I have some bad data in the database which I imported from Magento 1.9 via System -> Data Transfer -> Import

What happens is - when I go into:

```
- Catalog - Products
```

It gives the following Error:

> X Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
> restored the filter to its original state.

I've been through and around trying to identify which products are causing the problem but I can't get that done so I've decided to delete several pages of products and add them in manually.

When I set the filter to 20 per page - I am able to go through all pages one by one all the way up to page 115 out of 119 (that's where the Error starts).

I've tried truncating via:

```
TRUNCATE importexport_importdata;
```

*but even this no longer works.*

**How would I delete all products from pages 115, 116, 117, 118 and 119 when I can't actually load those pages in Catalog - Products?**

*The last product on page 114 has an ID of 2282.* I have access to phpMyAdmin.

---

**UPDATED on October 6th, 2023:**

Here are my logs:

**Debug.log:**

```
#0 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/ProductActions.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Undefined array...', '/home/MYSITE/p...', 61)
#1 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(396): Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions->prepareDataSource(Array)
#2 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions))
#3 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor))
#4 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(251): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#5 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#6 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
#7 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
#8 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#9 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#10 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#12 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
#13 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#16 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor))
#23 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#27 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#29 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#30 /home/MYSITE/public_html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#31 {main} [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.971707+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.971926+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972086+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972190+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972257+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972399+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972493+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972611+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972675+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
```

**System.log:**

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/ProductActions.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Undefined array...', '/home/MYSITE/p...', 61)
#1 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(396): Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions->prepareDataSource(Array)
#2 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions))
#3 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor))
#4 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(251): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#5 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#6 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
#7 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
#8 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#9 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#10 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#12 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
#13 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#16 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor))
#23 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#27 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#29 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#30 /home/MYSITE/public_html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#31 {main} [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.971707+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.971926+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972086+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972190+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972257+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.second', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972399+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'porto_header' respectively. [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972493+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972611+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sw.sidenav' tries to reorder itself towards 'category_leftnav', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-10-06T09:09:26.972675+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar_second_block' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.second' and '' respectively. [] []
```

---

---

UPDATED on October 7th, 2023:

**I tried to run the script provided by Nikhil Ajani but I get the following Error. I even tried changing the catalog_product_entity to mage_catalog_product_entity because I believe that would be correct in my case:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '%)' at line 1 in
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:90
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(90):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(106):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo{closure}()
> #2 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(91):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure))
> #3 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(313):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #4
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
> Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #5
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #6 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(564): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT` main_ta...', Array) #7
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(634):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #8 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(95): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #9 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #10 /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(1121): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #11 /home/MYSITE/public_html/pub/DeleteProduct.php(35): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->fetchPairs(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select)) #12 /home/MYSITE/public_html/pub/DeleteProduct.php(9): DeleteProduct->__construct() #13 {main} Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%)' at line 1, query was: SELECT` main_table`.`entity_id`,` main_table`.`sku`FROM`mage_catalog_product_entity`AS`main_table`WHERE (entity_id LIKE 2282%) in /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:109 Stack trace: #0 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(91): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure)) #1 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(313): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT`main_ta...', Array) #4
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(564):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #5 /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(634): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT` main_ta...',
> Array) #6
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(95):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
> Array) #7
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
> Array) #8
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(1121):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
> Array) #9 /home/MYSITE/public_html/pub/DeleteProduct.php(35):
> Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->fetchPairs(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
> #10 /home/MYSITE/public_html/pub/DeleteProduct.php(9): DeleteProduct->__construct() #11 {main} thrown in
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
> on line 109

---

---

Updated on October 10th, 2023:

**The initial script provided by Nikhil Ajani actually works:**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', "-1");
ini_set('memory_limit', "-1");
// ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

$exporter = new DeleteProduct();

class DeleteProduct
{
// Initialize the Mage application
    function __construct()
    {

        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

        $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

        $registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
        $registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

        $resourceConnection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);
        $connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();

        $select = $connection->select()
                ->from(['main_table' => "mage_catalog_product_entity"], ["entity_id", "sku"])
                ->where("entity_id LIKE '2283%'");

        $unUsedProducts = $connection->fetchPairs($select);

        if (!count($unUsedProducts)) {
            echo "No Unused Product found........";
            exit;
        }

        $collection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory::class)
            ->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", ["in", array_keys($unUsedProducts)]);

        foreach ($collection as $i => $product) {
            $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class)->delete($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please review your Magento logs to obtain the error information for this?

Comment: @GrazittiDev Hi Grazitti - I have uploaded my debug.log and system.log. These are the only 2 log files I have in my /public_html/var/log directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For delete product that ID start with 2282. For that you can create root script to delete those products.

**Create Below file in you Magento Pub folder**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', "-1");
ini_set('memory_limit', "-1");
// ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

$exporter = new DeleteProduct();

class DeleteProduct
{
// Initialize the Mage application
    function __construct()
    {

        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

        $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

        $registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
        $registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

        $resourceConnection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);
        $connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();

        $select = $connection->select()
                ->from(['main_table' => "catalog_product_entity"], ["entity_id", "sku"])
                ->where("entity_id LIKE '2282%'");

        $unUsedProducts = $connection->fetchPairs($select);

        if (!count($unUsedProducts)) {
            echo "No Unused Product found........";
            exit;
        }

        $collection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory::class)
            ->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", ["in", array_keys($unUsedProducts)]);

        foreach ($collection as $i => $product) {
            $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class)->delete($product);
        }
    }
}
```

You can run above code with URL **http://127.0.0.1/magento246/pub/DeleteProduct.php**
Let me know if you need any help.

**Thanks**

Comment: Thank you for that. When you say to create root script - would I just make a file, put your code into it and then call that up from somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: I just saw the URL you added. So just to make sure I do this correctly = make a file called DeleteProduct.php and put it on the root level of my Magento with your code in it, then just go to that URL such as this: www.MYSITE.com/DeleteProduct.php - is that correct?

Comment: @Allysin, Yes you have to create new file with name DeleteProduct.php in your magento PUB directory and then you can access like above link you say.

Comment: I tried running your script but I get an Error. Would you please take a look? I've posted the Error into my original post. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Allysin I have updated my script code. Could you please try once? I hope it works this time.

Comment: Just to confirm - I should upload the file into the pub folder under my public_html (that's where my Magento is installed) and then access it via the following URL, correct?  https://MYSITE.com/pub/DeleteProduct.php

I've tried this and it's coming back with my store's 404 Error.

Comment: Sorry sorry - I was doing it wrong. I did it again just now and it gave just a blank screen so I logged into the Admin panel but the products are not deleted.

Comment: After run script, could you please share your log ? it would be helpful to find error.

Comment: My sincerest apologies Nikhil - your previous code actually worked! It was just that I couldn't properly confirm it because of the Error and my Catalog -> Products not loading! I have since created a new Admin user and I can see that after I run your script, and go to Catalog -> Products - the number or products is 1 less. Feel free to change the code back to what it used to be (I've posted it into my original post also) and I'll be happy to accept your answer as the correct one! Thank you.

Comment: @Allysin Thanks. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this script, its a simple script to delete product you can modify accordingly

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\AppInterface;

try {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

try {
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');

    $registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

    // Using product id to remove product
    $product_id = 1; // Replace with the product ID you want to delete
    $product = $productRepository->getById($product_id);
    $productRepository->delete($product);

    echo "Product with ID $product_id has been deleted successfully.";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Hi Pramod - thank you for your code. I'm not sure if I have done this correctly? I've put your code into a file which I called 'Delete2.php' and I uploaded this into the pub folder located in /public_html/pub/ Your code also refers to \Magento\Framework\App\.. Do I need to find where that is located on my install and change the path accordingly? My Magento is insalled in root/public_html/. I also have prefix of 'mage_' in my database. I've uploaded the file and when I go to the URL = https://MYSITE.com/pub/Delete2.php I get: HTTP This page isn’t working ERROR 500 Thank you for helping.

Comment: update this line require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

Comment: also if you are not able to run it through standalone script create a sample cron for test purpose and put try catch block in it. and then execute that cron here is a link for  reference for cron https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/